# Node.js force download from another server

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I force download file from Google Storage without publishing my file's location. This is what I am doing so far. But it displays on browser instead of forcing to download:

```
...         
           if (req.method.toLowerCase() === 'get') {

                var fileUrl = 'https://yeketakclub.storage.googleapis.com/images/yeketak.club-4rjngDhckqZ9ZBmG2fsv.jpeg';

                var filename = fileUrl.split('/').pop();
                res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);

                request(fileUrl).pipe(res);

            } else {
                res.writeHead(404);
                res.end('Nein Nein :))');
            }
...
```

Comment: Cool Nein Nein reply :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var https = require('https');

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var fileUrl = 'https://yeketakclub.storage.googleapis.com/images/yeketak.club-4rjngDhckqZ9ZBmG2fsv.jpeg';

    var filename = fileUrl.split('/').pop();
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);

    https.get(fileUrl, function(res1) {
        res1.pipe(res);
    });
});
```